# fabric8 Informer for all Kubernetes Custom Resources in the cluster

Tags: java, kubernetes, fabric8, fabric8-kubernetes-client

I'm working with Kubernetes java library `fabric8` and I'm able to react in my code when new Custom Resources for a specific `kind` (like `MyCustomResource`). I'm using an `informer` for this. An example of this is here https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/main/kubernetes-examples/src/main/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/examples/CustomResourceInformerExample.java

Now, I want to go one step beyond, and I want to react to any kind of Custom Resources.

I've tried using the `GenericKubernetesResource` like this

```java
SharedIndexInformer<GenericKubernetesResource> informer = client.resources(GenericKubernetesResource.class)
                .inNamespace(kubernetesClientConfig.getConfig().getNamespace())
                .inform(myHandler, 60 * 1000L);
```

But at the time of running, I get this error:

```
18:33:13.563 [main] ERROR io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Error starting Micronaut server: resources cannot be called with a generic type
io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: resources cannot be called with a generic type
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.impl.BaseClient.resources(BaseClient.java:305)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.Client.resources(Client.java:175)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClient.resources(KubernetesClient.java:143)
```

Any help to implement an informer, using Kubernetes fabric8 library, to get a notice about any possible Custom Resource?